# Loading array in preg_replace

Tags: php

I'm trying to load my classes array in `preg_replace` but I am unable to get it to loop through the array. My 1st thought is, because I have a break in my code that is stopping the class from looping, however if I don't have a break in my loop the whole code will loop over and over instead of just the class string looping through.

This is what I have as my code, any suggestions?

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$classes = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black');
$i=0;
$html = file_get_html('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=^DJI&a=05&b=4&c=2012&d=06&e=6&f=2012&g=d'); 
$symbol_gainers = '';
foreach ($html->find('.yfnc_datamodoutline1 td') as $element){
    $symbol_gainers .= $element->outertext;
    $sym_gainers = preg_replace('~(class="yfnc_tabledata1")~', 'class="'.$classes[$i++].'"', $symbol_gainers);
    print_r($sym_gainers);
    break;
}
```

EDIT: [You can take a look at the code here with the functionality](http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=4DW972Uwjk6LvK_vX4ZqCQ).
Use Firebug to inspect the `td` of the HTML output, you will see it just repeats red red red over and over.

Comment: Is it that you just want to replace the class attribute? We do normally suggest here to not use simple html dom but just DomDocument or simplexml. In your case probably just DomDocument and DomXpath.

Comment: I went ahead and used an alternative route, im just trying to fix my undefined offset error now. Thanks for replying.